# Update mediante doble validacion

Tags: php, mysql, update

Que tal tengo el siguiente codigo PHP para realizar un update mediante 2 valores de referencia los cuales son el `Id_reg` y el `equipo`.

Pero cuando hago las pruebas me muestra el mensaje de `Update Realizado con Exito` aunque el valor `equipo` no coincida con el ya registrado y no me arroja un error.

Hice la prueba directamente con la consulta en la base de datos y me muestra el siguiente mensaje.

`Este es el registro a actualizar`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejecuto la siguiente consulta con el equipo erroneo

`UPDATE tb_registro SET fecha_sal='2023-01-16 16:19',sal='Salida' WHERE Id_reg = 19 AND equipo= R8`

Y me muestra lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo cual en el php no me arroja el mensaje de error si no el de `Update realizado con exitoso`.

No se cual es el problema agradeceria si me pudieran ayudar

Update.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$id_reg=$_POST["id_reg"];
$salida=$_POST["salida"];
$equipo=$_POST["equipo"];

$cont=0;
include("cn.php");
$msg = "";

$result=mysqli_query($c,"UPDATE tb_registro SET fecha_sal='$salida',sal='Salida' WHERE Id_reg = '$id_reg' AND equipo= '$equipo' ");

if($result == true){
    $msg = "Update realizado con exitoso";
}
else{
    $msg = "Equipo equivocado";
}

$result = $msg;
echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));

?>
```

Comment: Bueno.. tenes que diferenciar dos cosas.. El update no fallo... lo que paso, es que basicamente no actualizo ninguna fila.. pero eso no es un error...

Comment: Okey eso si lo entiendo, en este caso como podria hacer para que me muestre el fallo si no coinciden los equipos.

Comment: No soy experto en php, pero supongo tenes que controlar la cantidad de filas afectadas... que es distinto a saber si el query se ejecuto bien o mal...

Comment: Según lo que veo... ***todo tu código está bien***. Pero no se actualiza ninguna fila debido a que la doble validación no coincide en equipo. Tienes ***equipo P8*** en la base de datos e intentas actualizar ***equipo R8***, el cual no existe. Por eso todo está correcto.

Comment: @Tony_Bielo si yo se que por eso no se actualiza, por eso uso doble validacion si el equipo no coincide no me permite realizar la actualizacion de datos pero como logro mostrar el mensaje de error cuando no se realiza el update.

Comment: Recalco: No es un error, simplemente no se cumple una condición. Ahora bien, si deseas advertir al usuario que no hay filas afectadas, puedes averiguar cuántas coincidencias hay. Para ello puedes hacer primero un `SELECT COUNT(*)...` antes de actualizar. Es una alternativa a la respuesta de @A.Cedano

Answer (score 1):

Como bien ha indicado @gbianchi, el problema aquí es que no estás verificando la cantidad de filas afectadas, única forma segura se saber si un `UPDATE` ocurrió realmente.

En `mysqli`, la función para verificar eso es [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Aplicándolo a tu código, sería así:

```
$msg = "Equipo equivocado";

$result=mysqli_query($c,"UPDATE tb_registro SET fecha_sal='$salida',sal='Salida' WHERE Id_reg = '$id_reg' AND equipo= '$equipo' ");

if( $result && mysqli_affected_rows($c)>0 ){
    $msg = "Update realizado con exitoso";
}    
echo json_encode(array("result" => $msg));
```

Al poner esto `if( $result && mysqli_affected_rows($c)>0 )` estaríamos verificando no sólo si la consulta fue exitosa, sino que más de una fila fue afectada en esa consulta. NÓTESE que `mysqli_affected_rows` se invoca sobre la conexión, no sobre el resultado de `mysqli_query()`.

En cuanto a `$msg`, he preferido el estilo de asignación por defecto, es menos verboso, pues te ahorras el `else`. Por lo demás, esto es redundante: `$result = $msg;`, puedes hacer simplemente: `echo json_encode(array("result" => $msg));` con esa simpleza, nos hemos ahorrado 4 líneas de código.

**Nota sobre la seguridad:** Tu actual código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Convendría que implementes consultas preparadas para prevenir ese gravísimo riesgo.